# probability of set difference and independence

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence

I need to estimate the $P(B_i \backslash B_{i+1})$, where $B_i = (A_i \cup ... \cup A_2n)$ and $P(A_i) = \frac{1}{3n}$. Note that $A_i$ and $A_j$ are pairwise independent, but not necessarily mutually independent. I'm supposed to estimate this using probabilities of the form $P(A_i)$ and $P(A_i \cap A_j)$.

I know $$P(B_i \backslash B_{i+1}) = P(B_i \cap \neg B_{i+1})$$
Using the union bound, I could say that 
$$P(B_i) = P(A_i \cup ... \cup A_{2n}) \leq (2n - i)\frac{1}{3n}$$

but that doesn't help me as $B_i$ and $B_{i+1}$ are not independent events. Not sure how to handle this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align} P(B_i\backslash B_{i+1}) &= P(B_i\cap B_{i+1}^c)  \\
&= P\left(\bigcup_{j=i}^{2n}A_j \cap 
\left(\bigcup_{j={i+1}}^{2n}A_j\right)^c\right) \\
&= P\left(\left(A_i \cup\left(\bigcup_{j={i+1}}^{2n}A_j\right)\right) \cap 
\left(\bigcup_{j={i+1}}^{2n}A_j\right)^c\right) \\
&= P\left(\left(A_i \cap\left(\bigcup_{j={i+1}}^{2n}A_j\right)^c\right) \cup 
\left(\left(\bigcup_{j={i+1}}^{2n}A_j\right) \cap\left(\bigcup_{j={i+1}}^{2n}A_j\right)^c \right)\right) \\
&= P\left(\left(A_i^c \cup\bigcup_{j={i+1}}^{2n}A_j\right)^c \cup 
\varnothing \right) \\
&= 1 - P\left(A_i^c \cup\bigcup_{j={i+1}}^{2n}A_j \right) \\
\end{align}$$

Using the Bonferroni inequality,
$$ \begin{align} P\left(A_i^c \cup\bigcup_{j={i+1}}^{2n}A_j \right) 
&\geq P(A_i^c) + \sum_{j=i+1}^{2n}P(A_j) - \sum_{j=i+1}^{2n}P(A_i^c \cap A_j) - \sum_{\substack {j,k=i+1 \\ j\neq k }}^{2n} P(A_j \cap A_k) \\
&= 1 - \frac {1} {3n} + \frac {2n-i} {3n} - (2n - i) \frac {3n - 1} {9n^2} - \frac {(2n - i)(2n - i - 1)} {18n^2}
\end{align}$$

So you may combine the above results and obtain an upper bound. If you drop the latter two terms you obtain the opposite bound instead.